# Rails Strong Params Issue With Nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I am trying to render a `new` view on an already existing user show page. When trying to submit this view, I get `param is missing or the value is empty: user`. To be clear this is a *skill* partial being rendered on the *user* show page. For some reason it is using the strong params in my User Controller.

The code:

show.html.erb for user

```
<h4>Create a Skill</h4>
<%= render partial: "skills/form" %>
```

userscontroller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @skill = Skill.new
    @skills = @user.skills.all
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :avatar_url, :email, :about, :cover_letter, :city, :state)
  end
end
```

SkillsController.rb

```
class SkillsController < ActionController::Base
  def new
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @skill = user.skills.new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @skill = user.skills.new(skill_params)
    if @skill.save
      flash[:message] = "#{@skill.name} skill has been created!"
      redirect_to user_path(user)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_skill_path
    end
  end

  private

  def skill_params
    params.require(:skill).permit(:name, :level)
  end
end
```

Also, I have Namespaced skills within user. No authentication in place yet.

EDIT: @nickm, here are the contents of skills/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for(Skill.new, :url => { :action => "create" })  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Skill Name ' %>
  <%= f.input :level, label: "Skill Level ", collection: ["Beginner","Proficient", "Intermediate", "Advanced", "Expert"], include_blank: false, include_hidden: false %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's in `skills/_form`?

Comment: @NickM updated the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't passing a `user_id` through the form. You would have to either add a form input:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, some_value %>
```

Then find the user:

```
user = User.find(params[:skill][:user_id])
```

and then make `skill_params`

```
def skill_params
  params.require(:skill).permit(:name, :level, user_id)
end
```

Or optionally, set the value of user_id in your controller action. Not sure how you're going to pass that value since you haven't built any authentication yet. If you were using something like `devise` you could do

```
current_user.skills.new(skills_params)
```

...in your create action.

Comment: Incredible. I learned about hidden actions but haven't had a chance to use them yet. Thank you, I'm going to implement authentication now.